# Using JsonSerializer and DeflateStream to return compressed stream in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream, json.net

Right now I'm using JSON.net JsonSerializer to return data as stream in from my WCF services. The code is something like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public Stream GetJSON()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    return SerializeToJSON(resultDict);
}

public static Stream SerializeToJSON(object value)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();

    ser.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
    jsonWriter.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to add the DeflateStream somewhere and return compressed data.

Adding it directly to SerializeToJSON method don't work because I cannot dispose streams or WCF close them before returning data to clients.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution and reworked my code to better dispose streams.
From my understanding the returned stream can't be disposed because they are needed by WCF to handle returned data

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public Stream GetJSON()
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
    Dictionary<string, string> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    return Compress(SerializeToJSON(resultDict));
}

public static Stream SerializeToJSON(object value)
{
    var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var jsonStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(jsonStream))
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        var jsonSer = new JsonSerializer();
        jsonSer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        jsonSer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        resultStream = new MemoryStream(jsonStream.ToArray());
    }
    return resultStream;
}

public static Stream Compress(Stream plainStream)
{
    var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var compressor = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        plainStream.CopyTo(compressor);
        compressor.Close();
        resultStream = new MemoryStream(compressedStream.ToArray());
    }
    return resultStream;
}
```